# What does word value means in the String equals source code?

Tags: java, string, equals

While learning about @override and equals method I came across String equals() source code and I cant understand, what does **value** means? At first, I thought that it is some kind of keyword, but it isn't. I have tried to find any information in internet, but I can't. It feels like the **value** is probably array of character like {'H','e','l','l','o'}, but it's just assumption.

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String) anObject;
        int n = value.length;
        if (n == anotherString.value.length) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = 0;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                        return false;
                i++;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: value is a char array that the String class internally uses to save its content. You can see it in the source code of that class: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java

Comment: The `value` is an instance field of the `String` class, and yes it's a `char` array.

Comment: You can use IDE to navigate to where variables ware declared (usually by Ctrl + clickThatVariable). This should give you information about variable *type* which may also be useful information about purpose of variable.

Comment: Thank you! I will check this out :)

Comment: Note that in more recent versions of Java the `String` class was rewritten to store its contents as a byte array instead of a character array.

Answer (score 0):

It's the name of the reference that points to the array that contains the characters of the string. It's not a keyword.

Java has a notion of a ["value class."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) String is one. Integer is another. If a single field determines the "value" of the class it's typical for that field to be named "value." You saw that that is the case for String. Integer and Double follow that convention. But it's just that: a convention.